# How to get top k results from a table based on consequent updates

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I have a table with almost a million records(id from 1 to million).From the table I need to fetch top K(k=3,4,5 any number) rows with id1 and then update other rows(value in one column) based on the results. then again do it for top k for id2 and so on. the primary key for table is id, guid.

I have written this procedure with cursor to do this. I am passing number from 1 to million to this procedure from java ,but this is very very slow because use of cursors. Is there any alternative to it?

Thanks

Code snippet

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE displayGreedyAd (passedId IN int, k IN int)
IS
CURSOR topK IS
SELECT * FROM table G1 WHERE G1.Id = passedId AND G1.guid IN   
    (SELECT G.guid
    FROM (SELECT *
          FROM table
          WHERE table.somevalue <= table.Balance AND table.Id = passedId        -- this balance is updated below
          ORDER BY table.someothervalue DESC) G
    WHERE ROWNUM <= k)
    FOR UPDATE;

SingleRecord topK%ROWTYPE;  
BEGIN

IF NOT topK%ISOPEN THEN
    OPEN topK;
END IF; 

FETCH topK INTO SingleRecord;  

WHILE topK%FOUND 
LOOP
    IF (SingleRecord.somevalue >= SingleRecord.somevalue2) THEN
        UPDATE table
        SET Balance = Balance - SingleRecord.someothervalue -- this needs to be updated in the table
        WHERE table.guid = SingleRecord.guid; 
    END IF;

    FETCH topK INTO SingleRecord;  
END LOOP; 

IF topK%ISOPEN THEN
    CLOSE topK;
END IF;
END;
/

The table looks something like this

guid id amleft totamt amtspend  priority
1    1   20     20      7       2
1    2   20     20      11      1
1    3   20     20      2       3
2    1   30     30      4       1
2    3   30     30      12      2
2    4   30     30      7       3
..
..

After 1st iteration with k =1 and id =1 and subtracting last column with amountleft

fetch top 1 values for id=1 and lowest  priority and put it in a separate table(guid,id, amountleft,totalamount), after which this table will look like 

guid id amleft totamt amtspend  priority
1    1   13     20      7       2
1    2   13     20      11      1
1    3   13     20      2       3
2    1   26     30      4       1
2    3   26     30      12      2
2    4   26     30      7       3

then fetch for id =2 and so on, amleft gets updated after each fetch to a position where amleft < amtspend.

Thanks
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what the data looks like currently as well as what you would like it to look like when the code completes?

Comment: @Craig , updated the question above with sample table

Thanks

Comment: Is there a.reason for using stored proc? Sounds like this could be doable with a single query

Comment: Sorry.. I am still not clear what is going on..  It looks like you have subtracted the 7 from guid = 1, id = 1 from the amleft column of all the guid=1 rows as well as subtracted the 4 from guid = 2, id = 1 from the amleft column of all the guid=2 rows.  Is this correct?  How does priority come into play then?  What happens if K were inserted as 3 instead of 1?  What is the final output after all the iterations have run?

Comment: Btw, it's going to be slow, if you are updating 500k records on average. Here's a similar query without use of a stored procedure: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b4a75/2/1

Comment: Thanks,

I tried doing it without cursors , have some improvement but not that much. I think processing of 100k records will take some time indeed..